# GSON: Deserialize json response and return different set of objects

Tags: android, json, gson, retrofit2

I am trying to parse a json response using a GSON custom deserializer where after some modifications, it will return different set of objects. Currently, the sample json response is:

```
{
    "data": {
        "data_1": [
            {
            "attr": "linear",
            "item": [
                {
                    "category": "type1"
                },
                {
                    "category": "type2"
                }
            ] 
                            }
        ],
        "data_2": [
            {
            "attr": "relative",
            "item": [
                {
                    "category": "type3"
                },
                {
                    "category": "type4"
                }
            ]
                            }
        ]
    }
}
```

For this, the model class is created as DataResponse.java. This is the CustomDeserialzer.java:

```
public class CustomDeserializer implements JsonDeserializer {

    @Override
    public Data deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {
        // It will create list of data1 and data2 and will return instance of Data

    }
}
```

Data.java and DataItem.java:

```
class Data {
    private List<DataItem> data1;
    private List<DataItem> data2;
}
class DataItem {
    private String attr;
    private String category;
}
```

This deserializer is registered with gson with retrofit as:

```
final Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(endPoint)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory
                    .create(new GsonBuilder()
                .registerTypeAdapter(DataResponse.class, new ItemDeserializer())
                .create()))
            .client(okHttpClient)
            .build();
```

In this case, custom deserializer is called with whole json response and everything works fine. But it gets called for all the api call response. If the class type in gson builder is changed to Data.class, the deserializer is never called. How to achieve this functionality such that deserializer can return Data with proper values?

The interface will have the method as follows:

```
public interface ApiService {
    @GET("/getData")
    Call<Data> getData();
}
```

Comment: 1. this is not a valid json, 2. you datItem is not matching the json inside data_X 3. try http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/ for creating a pojo

Comment: @Fusselchen I have edited the json response for missing braces. Yes, DataItem does not match the json inside data_X and so inside deserializer, we have to take those data and set values according to DataItem class.

Comment: do you realy recieve that json? or do you think you get it? can you change your request to simple string, and than parse it with your Gson parser, just to verify if it is a problem with your call/recieving, retrofit handler, or gson.